# How can I use Qioptiq Mag.x LD Plan Apo 5x / 0.20 objective with Canon EF full frame or Lumix 5?

Tags: canon, macro, panasonic-lumix

I would like to make macrophotography with a [Qioptiq Mag.x LD Plan Apo 5x / 0.20 objective](https://www.closeuphotography.com/qioptiq-magx-5x-objective/2017/2/17/qioptiq-magx-ld-plan-apo-5x-objective) and a Canon EF full frame or Lumix GH5.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Maybe you can consider Canon MP-E 65mm which is also 5:1 (do not have focus on infinity) and cost only ~1000 euro. This lens you show have 34mm thread and I am afraid this is quite rare in ordinary photography and you can't easy find proper adapter to EF or M43.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post as I am looking for this exact lens myself. It is a very good lens, but a challenge to use. For use with a full frame sensor the company recommends  a 432.5mm tube lens, resulting in an 8.7:1 magnification. The standard tube lens is a 250mm focal length and gives you 5:1 magnification, but an image circle of 25mm in diameter, should be enough for your Lumix GH5.

The limited 13mm working distance makes things a bit difficult to work with, especially since it is a rather large lens.

I wouldn't recommend the MP-E 65mm, the optical performance (other than at 1:1) is not the best you can get for that price. The Laowa 2.5-5x is a good deal, as is the Laowa 100/2.8 2x (it outperforms the MP-E 65mm at 2:1). If you want a small macro lens, I rather like the old Canon 35mm f/2.8 MP, cheaper and better than the MP-E.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated at [the link in the question](https://www.closeuphotography.com/qioptiq-magx-5x-objective/2017/2/17/qioptiq-magx-ld-plan-apo-5x-objective) this objective seems to work as a microscope objective, i.e., it is like an oversized microscope objective. It needs to be used together with a tube objective (that would be located in the "tube", in a microscope). Adapting the M43 thread to a camera should not be much of a problem, as filter adapter rings should work (there are no electronics or mechanicals levers to deal with). So, if you do need the resolution and the camera sensor can make justice to it, it should be usable with a APS-C or M43 camera. As explained in the linked page, the image circle can be enlarged using a different tube lens. So it should be possible to use if you get all the needed parts including the tube lens, but is it worthwhile? As Romeo Ninov commented it would be easier to use a Canon MP-E 65mm (USD 1000 new) or a [Laowa 25mm f/2.8 2.5-5X Ultra Macro](https://www.venuslens.net/product/laowa-25mm-f-2-8-2-5-5x-ultra-macro-2/) (USD 400 new). Both are manual focus objectives. The Canon has contacts for EXIF data and diaphram, while the Laowa is fully manual. I haven't used either of these objectives, I have instead a very old [Olympus OM 38mm f:3.5](http://www.alanwood.net/olympus/macro-lens-38-35.html), fully manual objective usable with extension tubes. Either of these modern objectives or the Qioptiq should be better than my old Olympus at least with respect to image contrast.